# Angularjs save form input to php and Mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I have a promblem trying to learn and build an angularjs application. I just can't get the form data saved to mysql...
I have spent hours trying everything and it just won't work.

The PHP-file inputs empty queries to the mysql table when using the variable. If I use static info it works fine.

Thanks :)

```js
app.controller('addMsgCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.fill = function(add) {
var data = {
            addItem: $scope.addItem
        };
$http.post("msinput.php",{'data' : $scope.addItem})
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("inserted Successfully");
        });
        };

});
```

```css
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$addItem = mysql_real_escape_string($data->addItem);
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db("stran189_taskma") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (addItem) VALUES ('$addItem')"); 
Print "Your information has been successfully added to the database.";
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<form class="add-task" id="newTaskForm" ng-controller="addMsgCtrl" novalidate ng-submit="fill()">
        <div class="form-actions">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input ng-model="addItem" class="form-control" type="text" name="addItem" placeholder="Ny anteckning" />
            <div class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div> 
      </form>
```

RESPONSES
    **JS**: "Inserted successfully!"
    **NET**: "POST 200 OK msinput.php"
    **Request headers**: "Host: (myUrl)
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.11; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: (myUrl)
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 2
Connection: keep-alive"

**respond-headers**:
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 62
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Mon, 07 Dec 2015 21:36:53 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
Vary: User-Agent
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.37

Comment: Why do you use a modern frond-end framework, but outdated php?

Comment: Use the network tab in your developer mode to see what the post includes. Print the content of $data to your screen to debug.

Comment: $data is empty...
And it's running on a shared hosting service and I can't make installs to the server. Otherwise node.js + a noSQL db would have been a no brainer.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by your controller code, but it seems to me, that you prepare the var data to be send to the server. If this is true you have to $http.post("msinput.php", {'data': $scope.data}) ...

Comment: You're right I've been shuffling the code around so much that I missed that, thanks, but still nothing but empty db inserts.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your fill() log data. See if anythign is in there. The change this

```
$http.post("msinput.php",{'data' : $scope.addItem})
```

to this

```
$http.post("msinput.php",{'data' : data})
```

Then check your Network XHR and see if data is being sent correctly to the server.

Also to get more info on what the server is saying back you can also use this method and log the error:

```
// Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'msinput.php'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
 }, function errorCallback(response) {
      // called asynchronously if an error occurs
      // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

Comment: added responses to the top @shaneal

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your data is present:

Open Firebug in Firefox, choose the console tab

Navigate to your form in Firefox, fill in the the form and submit it.

The last line in the console should show:

```
POST http://..../msinput.php
```

click this and look at the POST & JSON tabs, it will show all your input data for each field. Anything missing obviously wont get to your db.

Once you know your data is leaving, then you can figure out why its not arriving.

I also strongly suggest you change to PDO and stop using mysql functions has it is now deprecated.

Ok, so now you know the data in your form is leaving thru your post action.

Inside your msinput.php do the following

```
var_dump( file_get_contents(http://input) );
```

See what comes back in the firebug console.

Comment: When I wrote "katt" into the form Firebug returned:
"JSON
data  "katt"
Source
{"data":"katt"}
inserted Successfully"

So yeah, that works.